# Define newenvironment using mdframed and align

Tags: environments, align, mdframed

I would like my math equations to have a gray background. My initial attempt at this was to simply "sandwich" my `align` environment by a `mdframed` environment. It would seem far easier to me though if I could just define a new environment which handles that task for me so that I have to type less code every time I would like to use equations in my document.

My initial attempt at the environment was the following:

```
\newenvironment{matheq}
{
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=gray]
\align
}
{
\endalign
\end{mdframed}
}
```

So that I can use math equations like so:

```
\begin{matheq}
1+1=2
\end{matheq}
```

Regrettably, this does not work and I get the following error code:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{mdframed} on input line 7 ended by \end{matheq}.
```

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This won't work this way, because of the special settings in `align` etc. environments.

Comment: No `\begin{...}` should be in the “start” code (and no corresponding `\end{...}` in the “close” part).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a `mdframed` approach, but the `tcolorbox` package has special settings to create coloured box wrappers for `ams` environments like `align`, `align*`, `equation` and `gather`, see p. 293 of current manual (v. 3.72)

I've defined a separate `tcolorbox` environment for this with `\newtcolorbox` and set the `ams align` key, it's possible to specify some options individually with each call. For numbered boxes see the manual please (pages 14ff and 97ff)

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{matheq}[1][]{ams align,colback=black!20!white,colframe=blue,#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{matheq}
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} &= \infty.\\
\int x^2 ~\text{d}x &= \frac{1}{3} x^3 + c. \\
1 + 1 &= 2
\end{matheq}

\begin{matheq}[colback=yellow]
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} &= \infty.\\
\int x^2 ~\text{d}x &= \frac{1}{3} x^3 + c.\\
1+1 &= 2
\end{matheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works beautifully! Many thanks Christian!

Comment: @ifilot: Fine, happy TeXing then!